# Quoted system command in R

Tags: r, csv, awk, quotes

I would like to use the system() command in R to send:

```
system("awk -F "\"* ,\"*" 'NR==1 || $4 == 2925204' input.csv > output.csv")
```

to terminal on my mac. In terminal, I could just run:

```
awk -F "\"* ,\"*" 'NR==1 || $4 == 2925204' input.csv > output.csv
```

Unfortunately, I'm not sure of how to make R read the quotation marks correctly.  Could anyone help me out?

Please note that I have had to add an extra space after the first asterisk so that stackoverflow's text editor will print this post correctly.

Comment: you need to escape the backslashes, and the double quotes, i.e. have `... -F \"\\\"* ...`

Comment: try `system("awk -F '\"* ,\"*' 'NR==1 || $4 == 2925204' input.csv > output.csv")`

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the awk's Field Separator value inside single quotes.

```
system("awk -F '\"* ,\"*' 'NR==1 || $4 == 2925204' input.csv > output.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're already in R, why not do the entire job in R? R has dedicated functions and much better suited for parsing CSV compared to Awk.

Here you go:

```
df <- read.csv('input.csv')
rest <- df1[-1,]
out <- rbind(head(df, 1), subset(rest, rest[,4] == 2925204))
write.csv(out, 'output.csv', quote=F, row.names=F)
```